# Format of the Path input in the Javascript Clipper

Tags: javascript, arrays, polygon

I'm using a JS Library called Javascript Clipper for polygon operation. As stated from the manual, the coordinate format of an input path is like the follows,

```
var paths = [[{X:30,Y:30},{X:130,Y:30},{X:130,Y:130},{X:30,Y:130}],
                 [{X:60,Y:60},{X:60,Y:100},{X:100,Y:100},{X:100,Y:60}]];
```

My question is, how to convert a regular JS array, say 
`var x = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10]` and `var y= [22, 32, 11, 45, 75, 19]` to the required format shown above? The actual case is, these coordinate points will not be typed manually, but obtained from another function, the output of which is not in the format required by the Javascript Clipper Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function makePath(xVals, yVals) {
    var pathArray = [];
    xVals.forEach(function(xVal, index) {
        var yVal = yVals[index];
        var coordObj = {xVal, yVal};
        pathArray.push(coordObj);
    })
    return pathArray;
}
```

You can pass it your arrays, x and y, as `makePath(x,y)` to get the combined array out.

My method assumes that the lengths of the arrays x and y are the same.